# read messages from JMS MQ or In-Memory Message store by count

Tags: jms, wso2, ibm-mq, wso2-esb

I want to read messages from JMS MQ or In-memory message store based on count.
Like I want to start reading the messages when the message count is 10, until that i want the message processor to be idle.
I want this to be done using WSO2 ESB.
Can someone please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by pushing the message to db and get as per the count required as in this answer of me take a look at my  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138913/how-to-retrieve-multiple-rows-from-database-using-wso2-esb/31154782)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with wso2, but from an MQ perspective, the way to do this would be to trigger the application to run once there are 10 messages on the queue. There are trigger settings for this, specifically `TRIGTYPE(DEPTH)`.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Morag's answer, I doubt that WS02 has built-in triggers that would monitor the queue for depth before reading messages.  I suspect it just listens on a queue and processes messages as they arrive.  I also doubt that you can use MQ's triggering mechanism to directly execute the flow conveniently based on depth.  So although triggering is a great answer, you need a bit of glue code to make that work.

Conveniently, there's a tutorial that provides almost all the information necessary to do this.  Please see [*Mission:Messaging: Easing administration and debugging with circular queues*](http://ibm.co/huFW3R) for details.  That article has the scripts necessary to make the Q program work with MQ triggering.  You just need to make a couple changes:

1. Instead of sending a command to Q to delete messages, send a command to move them.
2. Ditch the math that calculates how many messages to delete and either move them in batches of 10, or else move all messages until the queue drains.  In the latter case, make sure to tell Q to wait for any stragglers.

Here's what it looks like when completed:  The incoming messages land on some queue *other* than the WS02 input queue.  That queue is triggered based on depth so that the Q program ([SupportPac MA01](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMA01)) copies the messages to the real WS02 input queue.  After the messages are copied, the glue code resets the trigger.  This continues until there are less than 10 messages on the queue, at which time the cycle idles.